# $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overline{AB}$ vector notations

Tags: notation, vectors

Do $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overline{AB}$ both represent vector that starts at point $A$ and ends at point $B$?

Comment: The first one. The second one is used in geometry for the [line segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment) joining $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @lhf thanks. Infact both notations are used for same vector according to this quesion: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11515/why-do-some-people-represent-vectors-with-overbars-while-others-use-underlines